# How to make form access variable of a same form that is created in run time?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a form2 (TForm2) and it contains a button which can create a completely same form.

The code of the button :

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 NewForm: TForm2;
begin
 NewForm := TForm2.Create(Self);
 NewForm.Show;
end;
```

By using this way I will having a Form2 and a 'clone Form2', but I will be unable to access the 'clone Form2' from the Form2 as I didn't assign any uses clause.

Is there any way to access from Form2 to 'clone Form2', or either way from 'clone Form2' to Form2 ?

Comment: You might want to understand variable scoping and lifetime. Your second form isn't a "clone", it's a copy. And you can refer to it using `NewForm`. The form  that called it, can be referred to using `Form2`. If you make `NewForm` a public var of the TForm2, you can refer to it using `Form2.NewForm`. There's a lot of ways you can do this.

Comment: @nolaspeaker Thanks for your information. But if I using Form2.NewForm, I can only access to the first copy of Form2. If I create more copies, I can still only access to the first copy only.

Comment: "Copy" is not the right way to think about this.  You are creating multiple instances of the same form.  "... but I will be unable to access..."  You are misunderstanding the effect of the Uses clause.

Comment: If you want to access multiple instances, you must store them in some form of collection. Do you know what a collection is?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is Array a collection?

Comment: Yes, an array is one form of a collection. Exactly which collection works best will depend on how you want to retrieve items and refer to them. Also, do you still use auto created global vars like `Form2: TForm2`, because you should not do that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access multiple copies of form, you need to organize them into some list/array.

Such list already exists - [TScreen.Forms](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TScreen_Forms.html), but you need an idea - how to choose needed instance.